# Multi Select Box Jquery blur event

Tags: jquery

I have multi-select box,displaying cities.The user can select any number of cities at a time.When the user finishes selection,the jquery blur event is not getting triggered.If I do the same in javascript it works fine.The blur event gets triggered when the user releases the ctril key.

The city select box is populated when the user selects a country,and this is done using jquery ajax.

see this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Z6X8L/4/

Thanks in advance

Comment: hard to troubleshoot invisible code

Comment: can you put complete code which uses ajax as well? because here we got jsfiddle working as expected when blur event triggered.